# Vector bundles on $\mathbb P^2$ with vanishing Chern classes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $F$ be a rank $r>2$ vector bundle on $\mathbb P^2$ such that it has section(s) and both its Chern class vanishes. Is it necessarily true that $F \cong \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}^{\oplus r}$? (or atleast can we say that it is globally generated?)

Any suggestion regarding how these bundles behave is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the Euler sequence
$$0\to\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(-1)\to\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}^{n+1}\to T_{\mathbb P^n}(-1)\to 0.$$
This short exact sequence implies $T_{\mathbb P^n}(-1)\oplus \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(-1)$ and $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}^{n+1}$ have the same Chern classes, hence $T_{\mathbb P^n}(-1)\oplus \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(-1)$ has trivial Chern classes. But it is clearly not globally generated.